# How ansible find python modules on target and is it possible to use virtualenv to install modules dependencies?

Tags: ansible

I need to create some snake-oil certificates on some playbook and I'm using openssl_privatekey, openssl_csr and openssl_certificate modules for this. The problem is that this module depens on PyOpenSSL and that CentOS versions of PyOpenSSL are outdated.

To workaround this I install PyOpenSSL from pip, which works, but may overwrite an already existing PyOpenSSL module if that was installed with yum.

On my playbook I'm doing this:

```
- name: 'Install PyOpenSSL'
  pip:
    name: PyOpenSSL
    state: present
    version: '>= 0.15'
```

Now, is there a way to install this in a virtual environment, so that ansible is aware of it? If so I can simply remove the virtual environment in the play's end.

Answer (score 2):

You can *create* a virtualenv with the `pip` module. You can probably make Ansible aware of that virtualenv by setting the `ansible_python_interpreter` fact to point at the `python` binary in the virtualenv, so something like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: install modules
      pip:
        state: present
        name: "{{ modules }}"
        virtualenv: /tmp/venv
      vars:
        modules:
          - pyopenssl

    - set_fact:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /tmp/venv/bin/python
```

Caveat: I haven't tested this thoroughly. It didn't *break* anything.

Comment: Seems a good idea, how would I restore the old ansible_python_interpreter afterwards? I want to keep this encapsulated in a single role

Comment: Store the value of `ansible_python_interpreter` in another fact, and then at the end of your role set `ansible_python_interpreter` to `saved_ansible_python_interpreter`, maybe?